# 50 was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

My code is in a batch file.

The error:

> enter your age:22
>   50 was unexpected at this time.

```
@echo off
set /p age = "enter your age:"
if %age% leq 50 ( 
    if %age% geq 20 (
        echo "You are %age% years old in the 21st century."
            ) else (
                echo "You are not in range."
) else (
    echo "You are not in range."
)
pause
```

Comment: Do not put spaces on either side of the equals symbol in a set command.

Comment: You have also mismatched your parenthesis.

Comment: Batch recognises the space appearing before the `=` as a valid variable-name character, so you assign your input to a variable named "age ", not "age" The variable *age* is undefined and thus the command `if %age% leq 50 (` is interpreted as `if  leq 50 (` since `%age%`, being undefined, is replaced by *nothing*). Batch then sees `leq` as the first argument to be compared and `(` the second with the comparison to be `50` where it is expecting `==`, `equ`, `neq`, 'lss`, 'leq`, 'gtr` or `geq` so it reports the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your script. There were two issues

- As mentioned by Squashman, remove the spaces in the set command
- Imbalance in the parenthesis

---

```
@echo off
set /p age="enter your age:"
if %age% leq 50 ( 
    if %age% geq 20 (
        echo "You are %age% years old in the 21st century."
    ) else (
        echo "You are not in range."
    ) 
) else (
    echo "You are not in range."
)
pause
```